# Is Annotation the best approach ? If so, how to persist it?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, annotations

I am working on an eclipse plug-in where some warnings are displayed to the developer, but some of them may be false positives.

My idea is to provide an option where the developer can "ignore" the warning so that future verifications won't flag that code again.

I found the code below and it works, but every time I close the file, the annotation gets deleted.

```
public static void addInvisibleAnnotation(ASTNode node) {
    IAnnotationModel model = getAnnotationModel(getPath(getCompilationUnit(node)));
    if (null != model) {
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(Constant.INVISIBLE_ANNOTATION, true, null);
        int offset = node.getStartPosition();
        int length = node.getLength();

        Position position = new Position(offset, length);
        model.addAnnotation(annotation, position);
    }
```

There is a flag "isPersistent" and it is set to true.

So I have some questions:
01 - Is Annotation the best approach ?
02 - Do I need a marker for the annotation ?
03 - How can I persist it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations only exist when the text editor is open, so they're best used for exclusively in-editor features, such as identifying spelling mistakes. Markers are automatically represented by MarkerAnnotations when the editor is reopened. See https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html for how to work with Markers.